# Count items of json string in SQL script (compatibility version 100, no openjson)

Tags: json, sql-server, json-value, compatibility-level

My Json string has couple of items and I can use `json_value` to get specific items and parse it. But need to know the length of items to iterate.

```
[  
   {"name":"Ram", "email":"Ram@gmail.com"},  
   {"name":"David", "email":"David@gmail.com"},  
   {"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com"}  
]
```

For example `JSON_VALUE(@myJsonString, N'$[1].email')` returns `David@gmail.com` but I need to know the length to increment.

Am I doomed to use openjson?

Comment: If `OPENJSON()`  is not supported, probably a string-based approach is an option - `SELECT LEN(@json) - LEN(REPLACE(@json, N'{"name"', N'"name"'))` (the `@json` variable holds the input JSON).

Comment: yes, it worked for me even the final code seems a bit ugly.